# What does the bold line in the bash `top` command output signify?

Tags: bash

The `top` command in bash outputs something like

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 4724 root      20   0 4986596 4.425g  26404 R  47.2 30.1   3:49.97 python
 4681 root      20   0 7704444 602344  38844 S  12.6  3.9   1:15.40 java
  483 root      20   0 7727184 999976  29428 S   3.0  6.5   0:44.70 java
```

Except that in bash one of the rows is usually in bold.  Its usually the top (most resource intensive) row, but not always.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the output of `top` can be configured. Some distros (Ubuntu for example) will display *running* processes in bold letters by default.

Look at the `S` column. That means *state*. `R` means *running*.

---

For further info about the `top` options check the [`man page`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top) and/or use the (nice) interactive help which you can enter by pressing <kbd>h</kbd> when `top` is running.

Comment: Reference: https://linux.die.net/man/1/top (or `man top`).

Comment: Was just in this moment looking for a link. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It could be more than one row, and it indicates that the process is in a state of `RUNNING` according to `top`'s criteria. `man top` for more info on what that means. Look at the status column, and you'll see that all the highlighted rows contain `R` in this column.

It's not uncommon for most processes in the first page of `top` to be `S` for `SLEEPING`, because most processes are waiting for input or a time. Try creating a process that'll stay busy (`cat /dev/urandom > /dev/null` works), and you'll see both this and `top` highlighted in `top`.